# Get the TextArea to display all of the content without scrollbar using plain JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call to display a users details and allow the user to edit their details should they wish to, therefore I have placed their stored information inside a Textarea.  However, when I place this information inside a TextArea, the element does not display all of the content in a fashion that a DIV might, instead, the details e.g 'about me' appear truncated and can only be accessed via a scroll bar.

I would like the text inside the TextArea to be fully visible.

The answers I have found on Stack overflow involves expanding the TextArea as a user types in the text. I do not want this.  I just want to display the details already stored.  Please can someone advise how without jQuery

MY AJAX CALL creates and populates a form:

```
 if(about != '' || about != undefined || about != null){
    about = '<textarea id="iabout" class="editInput" type="text" onkeyup="memDet.restrict(\'iabout\')">'+about+'</textarea>';

 // NEED TO RESIZE TEXTAREA SO THAT IT EXPANDS TO COVER ALL 
 // TEXT
```

Comment: What does memDet.restrict('iabout')" do?

Comment: If you only care for the initial data: add the textarea to the document and set `height` to `scrollHeight`... `textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";`

Comment: instead of textarea you can use `contenteditable` attribute on a HTML element to behave just like it.

Comment: @mplungjan memDet.restrict - restricts certain characters to be entered only e.g a-z.

Comment: @user3297291, I am getting the following error : 'null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('iabout').style')' - how do I write the script to check if that element has loaded before changing its height?

Comment: You'll have to add it to the document before executing this code. I'm guessing there's a `innerHTML = about` somewhere? Run it after that...